# How to make summernote disabled or read-only without using scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

I have been trying to disable summernote conditionally by checking the flag status in my Java Spring MVC Web Application, after the form submission.  I have my summernote

Style sheet entry as

```css
<link href="$/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="$/summernote/summernote.min.js"></script>
```

And Form as

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="${rc.getContextPath()}/module/support/save-item">

<textarea id="my-summernote" name="iRequirement" <#if flag?? && flag == 0>readonly</#if>><#if si?? && si.iRequirement??>${si.iRequirement}</#if></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found you have to call the ID of the textarea - I have summernote drawing on all textareas with class .summernote but calling:

```
 $('.summernote').summernote('disable');
```

Does not work... instead

```
 $('#quote').summernote('disable');
```

Works great.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing `readonly` to `disabled` in the `<#if flag?? && flag == 0>readonly</#if>`?

Comment: Afraid you might need to call the `.summernote('disable')` to make it happen. I used summernote a long time ago and kinda remember struggling with some stuff.